# How can I get the name of the first key in a dictionary?

Tags: c#

I get the following error messages when I want to get the name of the first key [0] in a dictionary. In addition, I don't know how to get the first value of this key. The value is of type string[] and I want to get [0].

```
if (task.Result.Error.Error == PlayFabErrorCode.AccountBanned)
{
    var KeyName = task.Result.Error.ErrorDetails.Keys[0];
    var ValueOfThisKey = task.Result.Error.ErrorDetails.Values[0];
}
```

> Error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Dictionary.KeyCollection'
>
> Error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Dictionary.ValueCollection'

How can I get the name of the key and its value?

[image: Dictionary]

Comment: [ElementAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_ElementAt__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Int32_), for example `task.Result.Error.ErrorDetails.Keys.ElementAt(0);`

Comment: `Keys.First()`. However you should niot rely on the order of the keys, as it´s not guranateed to have any specific order.

Comment: var key = dic.Take(1).Select(d => d.Key).First() using linq

Comment: Explain what you mean by "the first key". Is that when you sort your keys? Or do you want insertion order?

Comment: I don't need to sort the dictionary. I think there is always just one key and one value in the dictionary. Therefore I just need the first entry [0] in the dictionary.

Comment: If there's always one key and one value, why do you use a dictionary to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `task.Result.Error.ErrorDetails.Keys.First()`.

Alternativly you may also query the first `KeyValuePair` from your dirctionary:

```
var kv = task.Result.Error.ErrorDetails.First();
var KeyName = kv.Key;
```

However you should not rely on the order of the keys, because `Dictionary<T, S>` does not have any guranateed order. If you really need a determinstic order of elements in a key-value-based map, you may use a `SortedDictionary` instead.

Comment: he can do `Dic.OrderBy(x=> x.Key).First();` to guarantee order

Comment: @styx that is, assuming they want the collection to be ordered by key, and not insertion order. For the latter, they'd just need a list.

Comment: @CodeCaster To be fair, that also applies to my solution using a `SortedDictionary`.

Comment: @CodeCaster true

Answer (score -1):

you can try Linq, here is an example, and it does matter what is your sort criteria, like HimBromBeere already mentioned.

```
[TestClass]
public class Class1
{
    Dictionary<string, string> ErrorDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
    { 
        { "","" },
        {"a","err a" },
        {"1", "err 1" }
    };

    [TestMethod]
    public void Method()
    {
        var firstKey = ErrorDetails.Keys.OrderBy(k => k, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).First();
        // firstKey == ""
    }
}
```